# separate from and to places from text using nlp python

Tags: nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp, spacy

I have a sample text like

'I'm travelling from Spain to India i.e on 23/09/2017 to 27/09/2017

From this type of text i want to separate from and to countries and dates.

How can i approach?

Comment: Start by reading the nltk book, then find yourself an annotated corpus with the categories you need, then come back and ask questions for the specific tasks you'll need help with.

Answer (score 0):

> To Install Follow These Steps https://spacy.io/docs/usage/

```
string = "I'm travelling from Spain to India i.e on 23/09/2017 to 27/09/2017"

import re
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')
doc = nlp(string)
sentence = doc.text
for ent in doc.ents:
    if ent.label_ == 'GPE':
        print ent.text
```

### Output

Spain
India

## Reference

https://spacy.io/docs/usage/entity-recognition